# Is is possible to accomplish this with the ternary operator?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it's possible to refactor the following code using the ternary operator:

```
if (HasKey("pagesPause"))
{
  Pause(GetInt("pagesPause"));
}
else
{
  Pause();
}
```

for example:

```
Pause(HasKey("pagesPause") ? GetInt("pagesPause") : void);
```

It does not work with `void` thought (I'm using c#).

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Refactoring is supposed to change code to be better maintainable. The second piece of code (if it was correct) is terrible compared to the first.

Comment: no, it is not possible. Could you pass any default value such as `0`, `-1`, `null`? The latter is possible if you make the `pagesPause` parameter of the `Pause` method a nullable (`int?`). If you do that, you could define a new method `GetIntOrNull` which encapsulates `HasKey ? GetInt : null` and your code would read as `Pause(GetIntOrNull("pagesPause"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to point out that `Pause(Int)` and  `Pause(void)` Do no have the same signature (naturally), so it's impossible to do this the way you tried (one call to two functions of different signatures).
The problem gets even worse if you take into account the limitations on the ternary operator stated in other answers.

Comment: true - since two overloads of a method are in fact two different methods that appear to have the same name. Which one to be called is determined at compiletime by matching the signature of the call and the one of the method.

Answer (score 2):

You could be a bit wasteful and use the conditional to select an action to call

```
(HasKey("pagesPause") ? () => Pause(GetInt("pagesPause")) : (Action)(Pause))();
```

Which fits the requirement though probably not the intent of simplifying the code.

Alternatively, if the no-arguments version is equivalent to calling with a given default parameter, you could find the value and pass that into `Pause(int)`

```
Pause (HasKey("pagesPause") ? GetInt("pagesPause") : INFINITY);
```

Though if there was a suitable default, I would be more likely to change `GetInt` so it checks for the key and takes a default value to use if there isn't one.

```
Pause ( GetIntOrDefault("pagesPause", INFINITY) );
```

Comment: +1 You basically "copied" my comment :-) (except for the fancy lambdas suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for.

```cs
var pauseValue = HasKey("pagesPause") ? Pause(GetInt("pagesPause")) : Pause() ;
```

Comment: That won't work, ternary operator should be use as expression.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work in any case. C# forbids statements like `true;`.

Comment: Nop. Pause() returs void. But it would compile if returned something.

Comment: Since I do not know what the function Pause does, no.